# How to Ignore label tag in Xpath?

Tags: html, xpath

I want only **test** from below HTML DOM.

Here is my xpath **(//label[normalize-space(text()='test')])[1]**

Through this i am getting both * and test,whereas my requirement is to get only **test**.Please help me in this regards.

Below is my HTML:

```
   <html>
      <script>
      </script>
      <body>
          <label>
             <label>*</label>
               test&nbsp
         </label>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression

```
//label[normalize-space(text()='test')]/text()[2]
```

It retrieves the second `text()` node of the outer `<label>`.

---

With XPath-2.0 or above you can use the following expression

```
//label[normalize-space(string-join(text()))='test']/text()/normalize-space(.)
```

It joins all the `text()` nodes of the `label` and then outputs a `normalize-space(...)`'ed string of the result. I don't know of any XPath-1.0 solution.

Comment: @zx485...is there any way to avoid to indexing like [2]?

Comment: @Sainathpawar: Yes. But only for XPath-2.0 or above. I edited my answer.